# Integer solution to a square root equation

Tags: number-theory

Given the following function: $$f(x) = \sqrt{36 x^2+16416 x +61084}$$ where x is an integer and the function also generates an integer value, is there an algorithm to determine its integer solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "solution"? Do you mean the x for which $f(x) =0$?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: are you asking for solutions to "$f(x) = 0$"? Or "$f(x)$ is an integer"? Or something else?

Comment: The term $72*x*228$ also hints at a typo.

Comment: Sorry , I can not figure out what to do with the 228

Comment: Sorry but the function f(x) generates an integer value. Also 72*x*228 = 16416*x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{ 36 x^2 + 16416 x + 61084}.
$$

For what integer $x$ is $f(x)$ also an integer?

---

We can write

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{ \Big( 6 x + 1368 \Big)^2 - 1810340 },
$$

therefore

$$
\Big( 6 x + 1368 \Big)^2 - 1810340 = \Big( 6 x + 1368 - p \Big)^2,
$$

so

$$
p \left\{  2  \Big( 6 x + 1368 \Big) - p \right\} = 1810340.
$$

Thus

$$
x = \left( \left( \frac{1810340}{p} + p \right) \Big/ 2 - 1368 \right) \Big/ 6.
$$

Note the symmetry

$$
\frac{1810340}{p} + p = \frac{1810340}{1810340/p} + 1810340/p.
$$

Using

$$
1810340 = 2^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 67 \times 193,
$$

we can use limited values for $p$, like $p=2 \times 5 \times 7$, which is equivalent with $p= 2 \times 67 \times 193$.

We obtain the following results:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc|c|c}
2 & 5 & 7 & 67 & 193 & p & x\\
\hline
\times &&&&& 2 &75203\\
\times & \times &&&& 10 &14859\\
\times && \times &&& 14 &10549\\
\times & \times & \times &&& 70 &1933\\
\times &&& \times && 134 &909\\
\times &&&& \times & 386 &195\\
\times & \times && \times && 670 &53\\
\times & \times &&& \times & 1930 &11\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 4):

You can write
$f(x) = \sqrt{(6(x-228))^2 - 1810340}$.

Now, $f(x)$ is an integer if and only if $(6(x-228))^2 - 1810340$ is a square.
Write $$k^2=(6(x-228))^2 - 1810340$$
so
$$1810340 = (6(x-228))^2 - k^2 = (6x-6*228+k)(6x-6*228-k)$$

Now you factorize $1810340 = 2^2 * 5* 7* 67* 193$.

So you have to solve $48$ linear systems of the form
$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
6x-6*228&+k &=& a \\
6x-6*228&-k &=& b
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

For all possible values of $ab = 1810340$.

Comment: $f(6195)$ is in fact not an integer (I just plugged it into Wolfram). One potential issue I see with your proof is that $x$ and $k$ are not independent, so you cannot simply solve the last system of equations.

Comment: No, I did a worse mistake. I made a mistake in completing the square. In fact, if you compute $(3*6195-228)^2-36713$ you get exactly $18356^2$. Ok, sorry, I made a mistake but I'm not erasing my answer.

Comment: That's fine. Mind if I edit it, though?

Comment: I am editing right now.

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{(6(x\color{red}{+}228))^2 - 1810340}$...

Comment: In the original question there was a $-$ sign, then somebody edited. However, It seems that who posted the question does not care much about it.

Comment: Simple practical reasoning of the solution, thanks. The original post did not however have any negative sign or terms.